# How to send all items in sql query

Tags: php, sql

I have a code that need to send mail every hour to specified mail address, and i want it's subject to be mysql query

code till now:

```
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if (!$retval) {
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $subject = "{$row[0]}  "; 
}
```

but it returns only last item in database, any help will be great :)

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*`! Its deprecated! Try PDO or MySQLi..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but sure it will work and avoid using deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

```
$subject = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $subject .= "{$row[0]}  "; 
}
```

Comment: this worked as i wanted :) ty a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Put you whole `mail()` function inside the while loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM))
{   

     $subject = "{$row[0]}  "; 
     //mail code here
}
```

Comment: no this send one by one, but i want all together...

Comment: then,better store all subjects in array and then use for i=0 to array_size-1 to process elements